# Theme.AppCompat removes action bar (toolbar)

Tags: android

When I use the following style

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    </style>
</resources>
```

My action bar (toolbar) is gone.

[image: screenshot]

In my manifest I have `android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`

I tried something like:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
```

Did not worked for me.

I am using an `FragmentActivity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using an FragmentActivity.

Change that to `AppCompatActivity`, or do not use `Theme.AppCompat`. `Theme.AppCompat` works with `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: Thanks, using the `AppCompatActivity` instead worked. I need to use Theme.AppCompat because I have a BottomNavigation!